# Php fetch_assoc fetch amount of data different with num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT username 
FROM comment_of_post 
JOIN users_info 
    ON comment_of_post.commenter_user_id = users_info.user_id
JOIN comment_info 
    ON comment_info.comment_id = comment_of_post.comment_id  
WHERE comment_info.post_id = ?
```

I test in localhost it should have 2 records like this two :
`abc` and `abced`

I also check the `num_rows`is also 2,but when I run `fetch_assoc()` and `var_dump()` it,it show me this result

```
array (size=1)   'username' => string 'abc' (length=6)
```

Which is only 1 record show in the array,another record `abced` is not shown in the array

Can somebody tell me what I doing wrong?

**EDIT** 
**Here is my function that use the query**

```
 public function getAllCommenterUsername($post_id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT username FROM comment_of_post 
                                            JOIN users_info ON comment_of_post.commenter_user_id = users_info.user_id
                                             JOIN comment_info ON comment_info.comment_id = comment_of_post.comment_id 
                                             WHERE comment_info.post_id = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$post_id);
        $result= $stmt->execute();

        if($result){
            $commenterUsername = $stmt->get_result();
            $stmt->close();
            return $commenterUsername;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

**I run the function like this**

```
 $username = $db->getAllCommenterUsername($post_id)->fetch_assoc();
 var_dump($username);
```

Comment: upload complete code...

Comment: please show the php code you're using to get records

Comment: ok 1 minute,I uploading now

Comment: show the line where you use fetch_assoc() and var_dump in you question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch_assoc` returns only row by row. You should use it in a loop.
`fetchall()` returns all rows in array.
If you're using PDO Mysql, check this http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: ya I should use a loop to store in array..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

you want to use `fetch_all()` like this

```
fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)
```

you would implement it like this

```
$username = $db->getAllCommenterUsername($post_id)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
var_dump($username);
```

documentation here

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 0):

> @ken use fetchAll_assoc() at the place of fetch_assoc()

```
fetch_assoc() = fetch only one row from the total found rows

fetchAll_assoc() = fetch all rows which are found
```

Comment: i test `fetchAll_assoc()` but fetchAll_assoc() just give me an error

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll_assoc() `

Comment: are you using pdo ?

Comment: try  fetchAll_assoc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: still the same sir

Comment: he's using `mysqli` not `PDO` that is why his error says `mysqli_result`